# Single computer - Multiple wifi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wifi-configuration, connection-sharing

We have multiple Raspberry pis with wifi dongles.

**What we are trying to do is to connect to them all via wifi simultaneously from a single computer so we can issue commands.**

Of course, a computer can only have a single wifi connection hence I'm asking this question in case there is a system/technique around that limitation.

I have also looked into having all the PIs on a single network and with unique IP addresses but for this project it's not going to work. That's because each PI is broadcasting it's own wifi network.

Comment: Umm, connect them to an access point guy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Of course, a computer can only have a single wifi connection

No – it can have as many connections as it has WiFi adapters. (I'm not sure whether Windows supports this, but Linux certainly does.) You *can* install multiple PCI(e) Wi-Fi adapters, and connect even more via USB.

On the other hand, if all networks use the same IPv4 subnet, Linux will require you to set up *policy routing* to be able to speak over multiple interfaces at once. (This is not required with IPv6, because you could use link-local addresses, or an unique ULA subnet for each device.)